# rails ajax breaking datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an edit form that uses ajax with :remote => true. Using unobstrusive javascript in edit.js.erb, I call

```
$("#entries").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('form')) %>");
```

which updates the div named entries in edit.html.erb. The ajax works fine, and the form is re-rendered, but now the datepickers don't work. How can I fix it? I figure the datepickers are initialized when the page is first loaded, but I don't know how to change this behavior.

I am using this datepicker.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/143355/datepicker/datepicker.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize every time ajax call is made. Because the html form is being changed for every ajax request.

So add the datepicker initialization in edit.js.erb

```
$('[data-datepicker]').datepicker();
```

Comment: Can you help find the initialization, I can't find it, and also tried to copy the entire file into edit.js.erb and it still didn't work.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/143355/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: Awesome, I got it. It was easy and for some reason I didn't think it was that easy. I will edit your answer and mark it as accepted.